# "command not found" but the "package is already the newest version"

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian, vps

So I want to run a code, and I get error command not found, but when I try to install it, it says that it is fully installed, I'am so confused.
I'm running Debian 7 Wheezy

```
bash: libavcodec-dev: command not found
root@vps304348:~# sudo libavcodec-dev libavutil-dev libswscale-dev libasound2-dev libpulse-dev libjack-jackd2-dev
sudo: libavcodec-dev: command not found
root@vps304348:~# apt-get install libavcodec-dev                                Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
libavcodec-dev is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
root@vps304348:~#
```

Screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EzOzW.jpg

Comment: something wrong with your screenshot

Comment: Your link isn't pointing to a screenshot. Edit your question and copy/paste your problem instead

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/tHNcj

Answer (score 2):

**libavcodec-dev** isn't a binary file, it's a development files for library.